# Weird ListView behavior in Universal Windows Apps

Tags: xaml, listview, win-universal-app

Our application was previously designed for Windows 8.1. We are now looking into porting it to Universal Windows Apps for Windows 10.

We have noticed a difference in behavior, specifically with **ListView / ItemsControl**.

- **Collapsed Visibility** is now eating up **space**. In Win 8.1, collapsed visibility does not have extra space
- Additional margins with ListViewItems, specifically if ItemsPanel is **Horizontal**. There seems to be around 10px right-margin always.

The weird thing is, for the 2nd bullet, changing it to **GridView** solves the margin problem. 1st bullet still remains though.

Has anyone else encountered this and how did you solve it?

Thank you

Edit: Code for reference:

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tables}">
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
</Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowTable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
        <!-- A lot of UI Element -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

This is my code. I have traced it and the Visibility for the Grid is working correctly (true / false, sets visibility correctly). The problem is, even if the "Grid" is hidden, the "GridViewItem" seems to still eat up space. It seems that the Width doesn't change for the GridViewItem. On Windows 8.1 app, there are no spaces.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Collapsed items shouldn't use space. Please share some code.  The ListBiewItem/GridViewItem have some spacings set to them by default. You have to change the *ItemContainerStyle* to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks Kai, I have provided the code reference. I do have ItemContainerStyle there but it still doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridViewItems have a default `MinWidth` defined. You have to remove it in the `ItemContainerStyle`. You can check the default template [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx).

```
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
```

I could not reproduce your additional margin problem. With the code shown above, all elements in the List appeared adjacent to each other.

Comment: Thanks Kai! That worked! I compared the default styles of Win8 and Win10 ListViewItem and there were a lot of changes, including the MinWidth. 

Will need to take a look at the others now that I have an idea of what's wrong.